# Aes encryption with CryptoJS

Tags: javascript, encryption

I am trying to encrypt data with aes with following code.

```
var CryptoJS = require("crypto-js");

var key = '956479999968698999415547894568134';

var salt = '36521412345678';
var key = CryptoJS.PBKDF2(key, salt, { keySize: 256 / 32, iterations: 1000 });
var iv = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.random(256 / 8);
var cprEncrypt = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt("1234", key, { 'iv': iv });

console.log(cprEncrypt.toString());
```

My code works perfectly but not same with my .net ecrypted value.
I think iv is not same. I am getting iv in .net like this:

```
// generate the key from the shared secret and the salt

Rfc2898DeriveBytes key = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(sharedSecret, _salt);

// Create a RijndaelManaged object
// with the specified key and IV.
aesAlg = new RijndaelManaged();
aesAlg.Key = key.GetBytes(aesAlg.KeySize / 8);
aesAlg.IV = key.GetBytes(aesAlg.BlockSize / 8);
```

how can I fix this? How can I get same value in .net and js?

Answer (score 1):

**In java script** you generate a **random IV**. This IV you need to keep together with the encrypted data. Often the IV is just put in front of the encrypted data, so you have it when you need it. Just keep it in clear, it's not secret.

**In .net** you instead set it from the **content of the key** which won't work as it needs to be the same as the one used when encrypting. Also it's **bad practice** to use the **key as IV** as it in some cases can be used for **breaking the encryption**.